# C2027 use of undefined type 'Variable'

Tags: c++, class, composition, build-error

I working on object that can be used to store any datatype including collections of other datatypes. However, when I try to implement the stack datatype I getting use of undefined type error. I know this means the class is being initialized before it is defined but I don't know how to fix it.

Variable.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Datatypes.h"
#include "IntegerValue.h"
#include "FloatValue.h"
#include "StringValue.h"
#include "BooleanValue.h"
#include "ListValue.h"
#include "DictionaryValue.h"
#include "StackValue.h"
#include <vector>

class Variable
{
public:
    Variable();
    Variable(const Variable& src);
    ~Variable();
    Variable(int value, int lockMode = 0);
    Variable(double value, int lockMode = 0);
    Variable(std::string value, int lockMode = 0);
    Variable(const char* value, int lockMode = 0);
    Variable(bool value, int lockMode = 0);

    long long getInteger() const;
    double getFloat() const;
    std::string getString() const;
    bool getBoolean() const;
    bool isNone() const;

    void setInteger(long long value);
    void setFloat(double value);
    void setString(std::string value);
    void setBoolean(bool value);
    void makeList();
    void makeList(Datatypes dt);
    void makeDictionarly();
    void makeDictionarly(Datatypes dt);
    void makeStack();
    void makeStack(Datatypes dt);
    void makeNone();

    // List
    void appendListElement(Variable value);
    Variable& getListElement(unsigned int index);
    Variable getListElementCopy(unsigned int index) const;
    void setListElement(unsigned int index, Variable value);
    void removeListElement(unsigned int index);
    unsigned int getListElementsCount();
    void clearListElements();
    void fillList(unsigned int targetSize, Variable fillValue);
    void pruneList(unsigned int targetSize);

    // Dictionarly
    bool keyExists(std::string key);
    Variable& getDictionarlyElement(std::string key);
    void setDictionarlyElement(std::string key, Variable value);
    void removeDictionarlyKey(std::string key);
    void clearDictionarlyKeys();

    // Stack
    bool isStackEmpty();
    unsigned int stackSize();
    void stackPush(Variable value);
    Variable stackPop();


    Datatypes getDatatype();
    void setLockMode(unsigned int mode);

    static std::string datatypeName(Datatypes dt);

    static Variable createList();
    static Variable createList(Datatypes dt, bool locked = false);
    static Variable createDictionarly();
    static Variable createDictionarly(Datatypes dt, bool locked = false);
    static Variable createStack();
    static Variable createStack(Datatypes dt, bool locked = false);

    void operator=(const Variable& other);
private:
    VariableValue* m_value; // Pointer to the value stored in the variable
    Datatypes m_datatype; // Datatype of value store in the variable
    Datatypes m_elementDatatype; // The datatype the collection elements are locked to if locked
    unsigned char m_lockMode; // 0: unlocked 1: type locked 2: value locked
    bool m_elementTypeLocked; // If true the elements of the collection are locked to m_elementDatatype
};
```

StackValue.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Variable.h"
#include <stack>

class Variable;

class StackValue:public VariableValue
{
public:
    StackValue();
    StackValue(const StackValue& src);
    ~StackValue();

    void push(Variable value);
    Variable pop();
    unsigned int size();
    bool isEmpty();

private:
    std::stack<Variable> m_valueStack; // if this is commented out the error goes away
};
```

StackValue.cpp

```cpp
#include "StackValue.h"

StackValue::StackValue()
{
    m_valueStack = std::stack<Variable>();
}

StackValue::StackValue(const StackValue& src)
{
    m_valueStack = src.m_valueStack;
}

StackValue::~StackValue()
{

}

void StackValue::push(Variable value)
{
    //m_valueStack.push(value);
}

Variable StackValue::pop()
{
    Variable top = m_valueStack.top();
    m_valueStack.pop();
    return top;
}

unsigned int StackValue::size()
{
    return m_valueStack.size();
}

bool StackValue::isEmpty()
{
    return m_valueStack.empty();
}
```

I tried moving around the includes and forward declarations. They made no difference.

Comment: You have a circular include - `Variable.h` includes `StackValue.h` and vice versa. There can be no circular includes in your program. You have to modify your design such that one of the classes doesn't require full definition of the other class (i.e., it only uses pointers or references to the other type in the class definition - method definitions would be fine). There can be no simple answer to your question, the classes are inherently flawed and you need to fix that.

Comment: *...object that can be used to store any datatype...*  What's wrong with `std::any`?

Comment: Looks like `Variable.h` should not include `StackValue.h` and likely most of the headers it includes. It does not need to know about `StackValue` since there is no use of this object in the `Variable.h` header.